# Add a contact using Google Contacts API Version 3.0 & OAuth 2.0 in C# and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth-2.0, google-contacts-api, google-console-developer

I have created the developer's account, got my client-id and secret key. I'm new to C#, I'm able to retrieve contacts using using C#. Can anyone post the code for adding a new contact entry? Google has proper documentation for this purpose, but I'm having problem to implement it using C#. Please help!

Thank you

I Could Accomplish using PHP (Adding a Contact)

Here is the code

```
<?php

$group_id = "6"; // Used as the default 'My Contacts' group.

require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Google Apps PHP Starter Application");
$client->setScopes(array(
'https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/groups/',
'https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/alias/',
'https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/user/',
'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/',
'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/user/',
 ));


$client->setClientId('#################################');
$client->setClientSecret('***************************');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/try/index.php');
$client->setDeveloperKey('DEVELOPER_KEY');

if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
$client->authenticate();
$_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
$redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {

$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
$token = json_decode($_SESSION['access_token']);


$auth_pass = $token->access_token;



//Get Email of User ------------------------------------
// You are now logged in
// We need the users email address for later use. We can get that here.


$req = new Google_HttpRequest("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full");
$req->setRequestHeaders(array('GData-Version'=> '3.0','content-type'=>'application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8; type=feed'));

$val = $client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req);

  // The contacts api only returns XML responses.
  $response =$val->getResponseBody();

$xml = simplexml_load_string($response); // Convert to an ARRAY

$user_email = urlencode($xml->id); // email address
unset($xml); // clean-up

//-------------------------------------
// How to save an entry to your My Contacts List

// This is an example contact XML that Google is looking for.


$contact="
<atom:entry xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
    xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'
    xmlns:gContact='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008'>
  <atom:category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind'
    term='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact'/>
  <gd:name>
     <gd:givenName>abc_Name</gd:givenName>
     <gd:familyName>abc_familyname</gd:familyName>
     <gd:fullName>abc_fullname</gd:fullName>
  </gd:name>
  <atom:content type='text'>
  abc_Description</atom:content>
  <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo' type='image/*'
    href='https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/userEmail/contactId'
    gd:etag='photoEtag'/>
  <gd:email rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work'
    primary='true'
    address='abc@gmail.com' displayName='E. Bennet'/>
  <gd:phoneNumber rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work'
    primary='true'>
    9999999999999
  </gd:phoneNumber>

  <gd:structuredPostalAddress
      rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work'
      primary='true'>
    <gd:city>abc_city</gd:city>
    <gd:street>abc_street</gd:street>
    <gd:region>abc_state</gd:region>
    <gd:postcode>abc_pin</gd:postcode>
    <gd:country>abc_nation</gd:country>
    <gd:formattedAddress>
            abc_formatted address
    </gd:formattedAddress>
   </gd:structuredPostalAddress>
   <gContact:groupMembershipInfo deleted='false' href='http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/".$user_email."/base/6'/>
  </atom:entry>";


  $len = strlen($contact);
  $add = new Google_HttpRequest("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/".$user_email."/full/");
  $add->setRequestMethod("POST");
  $add->setPostBody($contact);
  $add->setRequestHeaders(array('content-length' => $len, 'GData-Version'=> '3.0','content-type'=>'application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8; type=feed'));

  $submit = $client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($add);
  $sub_response = $submit->getResponseBody();


  $parsed = simplexml_load_string($sub_response);   
  $client_id = explode("base/",$parsed->id);

  // Contact Groups -------------------------------------------------
 // This section will collect all the groups for this user for contact sorting.
// For now, I have set the default group to "My Contacts" of that user.


$group="http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fm8%2Ffeeds%2Fgroups%2F".$user_email."%2Fbase%2F6";


//Get Contacts by Group -------------------------------------------------------------------
// Now we request the users contacts based on group. For now, we will retreive 'My Contacts'


$req = new Google_HttpRequest("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/".$user_email."/full?group=".$group);
$req->setRequestHeaders(array('GData-Version'=> '3.0','content-type'=>'application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8; type=feed'));
$val = $client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req);

  // The contacts api only returns XML responses.
  $response =$val->getResponseBody();


    $xml = simplexml_load_string($response); // Convert the response to an ARRAY

//print_r($xml);

        echo "Group: ".$xml->title."<br>";
        echo "Email: ".$xml->id."<br>";
        echo "<hr><br>";

        for($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($xml->entry); $i++)

            {

            echo $xml->entry[$i]->title."<br>";

            }



// The access token may have been updated lazily.
$_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}

if(isset($authUrl)) {
print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
} else {
 print "<a class='logout' href='?logout'>Logout</a>";
}
```

I could Get a working C# code for retrieving contacts from [here](http://www.yogihosting.com/blog/implementing-google-contacts-api-version-3-0-oauth-2-0-in-csharp-and-asp-net/)

Comment: You should post what you have so far - where are you stuck? Please **show some effort** first before just asking for code!

Comment: Sorry marc_s this is my first post in stack overflow. Now I have edited the question. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The [Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) developer page some samples that can be beneficial for you.

This is the code sample taken from the Creating Accounts section in .NET.

```
public static Contact CreateContact(ContactsRequest cr)
{
  Contact newEntry = new Contact();
  // Set the contact's name.
  newEntry.Name = new Name()
      {
    FullName = "Elizabeth Bennet",
    GivenName = "Elizabeth",
    FamilyName = "Bennet",
      };
  newEntry.Content = "Notes";
  // Set the contact's e-mail addresses.
  newEntry.Emails.Add(new EMail()
      {
    Primary = true,
    Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsHome,
    Address = "liz@gmail.com"
      });
  newEntry.Emails.Add(new EMail()
      {
    Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsWork,
    Address = "liz@example.com"
      });
  // Set the contact's phone numbers.
  newEntry.Phonenumbers.Add(new PhoneNumber()
      {
    Primary = true,
    Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsWork,
    Value = "(206)555-1212",
      });
  newEntry.Phonenumbers.Add(new PhoneNumber()
      {
    Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsHome,
    Value = "(206)555-1213",
      });
  // Set the contact's IM information.
  newEntry.IMs.Add(new IMAddress()
      {
    Primary = true,
    Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsHome,
    Protocol = ContactsProtocols.IsGoogleTalk,
      });
  // Set the contact's postal address.
  newEntry.PostalAddresses.Add(new StructuredPostalAddress()
      {
    Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsWork,
    Primary = true,
    Street = "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy",
    City ="Mountain View",
    Region = "CA",
    Postcode = "94043",
    Country = "United States",
    FormattedAddress = "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy Mountain View",
      });
  // Insert the contact.
  Uri feedUri = new Uri(ContactsQuery.CreateContactsUri("default"));
  Contact createdEntry = cr.Insert(feedUri, newEntry);
  Console.WriteLine("Contact's ID: " + createdEntry.Id)
  return createdEntry;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, Ya I have been through this documentation. I don't know how to integrate with the Oauth token, and when to call this file and get response  etc.

Comment: can anyone point us to right direction? this answer is useless since i's a copy paste from the docs.